# How to parse JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to parse JSON sent by POST to my webservice. 
I'm using Advanced Rest Client tool for Google Chrome to test restapi.

How can I read this request and response to it?

I'm sending key called "format" and "json" as value for this key. I'm adding JSON like

```
"{"id":"235325"}"
```

Part of my PHP API code:

```
if( strcasecmp($format,'json') == 0 )
{
   //how to read that id = 235325?
}
```

Comment: can you past the content of  var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: but how? I'using Google Chrome plugin called Advanced Rest Client. And i'am waiting for response.

i dont kwno how to attach this json: "{"id":"235325"}" to link: http://78.28.23.180/index2.php?format=json

on webbrowser

Comment: the plugin may not support post data, use curl from your application and post data a to file expecting post. return the result.

Comment: @mdamia the problem is not getting the data to the server, but how to handle it once it is Inside the server

Answer (score 4):

Try the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function. It is the standard function to parse json in php.

Comment: Would it help the OP, and other viewers of your answer,  to explain why this function applies to this problem? And a visit to the manual will be worthwhile?

Answer (score 0):

If want to work with array:

```
$json = '{"id":"235325"}';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($array as $element){
if($element == 0){

}
}
```

With object:

```
$json = '{"id":"235325"}';

$object = json_decode($json);

if($object->id == 0){

}
```