# How to parse a JSON string in PHP?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I am parsing this JSON data in Java. I do have basic knowledge of PHP but I am unable to parse this JSON data with PHP, can someone help me do so?

**my_jsonEncode.json**

```
{
    "server_response": [
        {
            "error": true,
            "instId": "1",
            "instName": "abc",
            "instDescription": "my description",
            "instLogo": "web.com/image/mylogo.jgp"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: use `json_decode()` function of PHP and loop through the result array.

Comment: Try this example: [https://3v4l.org/6d1dV](https://3v4l.org/6d1dV), Here you found both resultant array and value access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125408/how-to-parse-json-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$json = '{
"server_response": [
    {
        "error": true,
        "instId": "1",
        "instName": "abc",
        "instDescription": "my description",
        "instLogo": "web.com/image/mylogo.jgp"
    }
]
}';
$result = json_decode ($json);
echo $result->server_response[0]->instId.' ';
echo $result->server_response[0]->instName.' ';
echo $result->server_response[0]->instDescription.' ';
echo $result->server_response[0]->instLogo.' ';
```

Edit: It convert Json to php object. Since there is only on Json array, you can get directly the element. If you have more array inside of Json then you can foreach each $result->server_response. For example :

```
foreach($result->server_response as $item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Php has two build-in functions (mainly) to work with JSON this are:

- json_encode(param)
- json_decode();

The later one return an associative array with the key value pairs.